# Skip same product data migration tool Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

How we can skip the same product data migration?

Any reference would be helpful

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do incremental data migration using delta

you can read here more

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

only changes updated after last migration will only migrate with delta